# 3 Level Horizontal Scrolling Menu (Possibly over-ambitious!)

Tags: jquery, html, css

The attached image probably shows best what I am trying to do, it is for an Irish rugby project. The menu allows you to select firstly the region, then the club, then the team.

The contents of each level is dependent on the selection in the one above.

I suppose initially I would just show the first menu level, and when an element is selected on this level, a second level will be populated based on that selection and will slide down, into visibility. The same would then happen for a third list.

Are there any easy jquery ways of doing this? Also, is there a less clunkier way of handling the scrolling than a scroll bar on each of them?

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction.

Alan

[image]

Comment: Your image didn't show up on this question. Can you post the full URL to it instead?

Comment: This is called cascading menu and is not too hard to implement. Depending on the size of your data you could consider to extract each level using AJAX calls fetching the data from a database. Alternatively you could hardcode the data in javascript.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the quick response, sorry, have uploaded the picture to: http://noroomformushrooms.ie/menu.jpg.

Comment: Muleskinner, I think AJAX could certainly be a possibility although I'd be concerned about a slight lag once the buttons were pushed. Given that there may be four regions, each with about twenty club names each, and maybe an average of 5 teams in each, is the better alternative to use a backend database and just load all the lists into three arrays, and use javascript to call on them as necessary?

Comment: @Alan: yes, that is possible. you could load them all at once during page load in a json array and place it in a script tag of the page

Comment: Thanks fskreuz. To come back to the cascading menu which jwiscarson mentioned, does anybody know if there's a tutorial anywhere on how to implement as per my picture with three horizontal levels? I just feel this would easier to scroll through rather than the usual sub menus...